# How to show $f(x) \to 1$?

Tags: functions

Let $$f(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}-2x}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}.$$

How do I show that as $x$ gets larger (positively), $f(x) \to 1$? According to WolframAlpha, $f$ is always less than or equal to one. I don't see why it is true.

Comment: for $x$ large positive, $e^x >>x.,$  therefore you basically have $\frac{e^x}{e^x}.$  all this will become much clearer if you will just evaluate the quotient $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}-2x}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}$  for $x = 10$(say).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply by $1$ in the carefully chosen form $\dfrac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$.

**Added:** To see that $f(x)\le 1$, start by rewriting it:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}-2x}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}=1-\frac{2(e^{-x}-1+x)}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}\;.$$

Next, note that $e^x+e^{-x}-2>0$ for $x\ne 0$: its derivative is $e^x-e^{-x}$, which is negative for $x<0$, $0$ at $x-0$, and positive for $x>0$, so $e^x+e^{-x}-2$ attains its minimum at $x=0$, and that minimum is $0$.

Finally, for $x>0$ we have $e^{-x}>1$, so $e^{-x}-1+x>0$. Thus,

$$\frac{2(e^{-x}-1+x)}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}>0$$

for $x>0$, and therefore $f(x)<1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any nice of showing $f(x) \leq 1$ when $x > 0$? I tried showing $f'(x)$ is positive but this is hard to see.

Comment: @Upin: I’ve added a proof that $f(x)<1$ when $x>0$.

Comment: @Upin: You’re welcome.